# WSO2 IS - SCIM2.0 API - Create User without setting password

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, scim2

I want to call the SCIM2.0 API to create a new user. In the documentation it's written that one of the field of the request body must be the user password. But I'd like to create the user without setting a password and sending him an email with a link to set it himself. Is it possibile? Because when I try to call the api without sending the password in the body, I get an error "password must not be a null string".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ask password feature to get this done. [1] In this doc check the Enable the invitation flow -> Use the SCIM2 API

Here the Identity Server will set a temporary random password until the user provides a proper password

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/identity-lifecycles/invitation-workflow/#use-the-scim2-api

Comment: Thanks! I've got a question... in my settings I specify that the user account must be locked (lock_on_creation=true) untill he provides a password, but if I try to access to the account with the random password that wso2 created, the login is successfull. Why is that?